# Angular span conditional hover over text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, controller

I am getting 3 values from the backend : isDone, isInProgress, isFailed and based on these 3 values, i need to change the hover over text of a span element in angularview. if the element is isDone or isInProgress, i have to show one icon with 2 different hover text. if the element is isFailed , i have to show an error message on the screen:

The code :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh blue"                                                      
 title="In progress" ng-show="action.isInProgress"> </span>
```

How do i incorporate the IsDone in this span?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh blue" title="{{ action.isInProgress ? 'Action is in progress' : 'Action is complete.'}}" ng-show="action.isInProgress||action.isDone"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks you. This really helped :)

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh blue"                                                      
 title="{{status}}" > </span>
```

and update your `status` variable depending on the value, as `"In progress", or ..`

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional checks

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh blue"                                                      
     title=" Action is Complete" ng-if="action.isDone"> </span>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh blue"                                                      
     title="Action in progress" ng-if="action.isInProgress"> </span>
```

Comment: and how do i toggle the hover on text (title) based on ng-show?

Comment: You can assign the text to your title tag, title={{yourVariable}}

Comment: what i mean to ask is, if the ng-show is action.isInProgress, the title(hover) should show - Action in progress and if ng-show is action.isDone, the title should show - Action is Complete. How can that be achieved?

Comment: You can do it as suggested by @Rahi Shah